# TCP Holepunch implementation

Tags: php, networking, hole-punching

I'm working on an idea of mine which is comparable to a home automation system.
The layout of network devices would be like this:
[image]

What I want is for my Mobile Phone App to be able to communicate with the home server at all times, but also for the server to be able to reach my phone (Push-notifications).
For this I thought it would be a good idea to implement TCP-Holepunching using my server in the datacenter as the center for traffic.

The problem is though, Since my Java skills aren't good enough yet, I'm forced to write my server in the PHP scripting language, but PHP isn't capable of keeping sockets active.

Is there TCP-holepunching server software (executable in Debian) available which would be able to keep the sockets alive and push any commands from my server towards the correct destination (ie: phone) and vice versa?

Comment: Concerning your bounty: It is not possible to provide a working solution with that little information. There are many variables, e.g. What do you mean by "firewall"? A NAT? HTTP-only? Which types of phones do you intend to use? Have a look at the XMPP protocol, for the phone maybe also BOSH.Can't be more specific than that, though.

Comment: basically I should be able to set up a connection from wherever I am as long as the device is able to set-up a connection to the server in the datacenter, that connection has to be kept alive to be able to communicate over

Comment: I may have misspecified "working answer" though, What I mean is some kind of code-example to work from instead of just telling me if you use code A and library B you should be able to create product C

Comment: What Phone make are you using ? Most modern phone already have push notification ...

Comment: Android 4.2, they support push-notifications but there will be some cases in which my server will not be able to reach it (for example behind a NAT or firewall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to get sockets working in PHP. One library that does this can be found here:
http://socketo.me/

Also an easy way of setting a server like this up can be done with [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/). You code your server in JavaScript (run on Google Chrome's V8 Engine) and then you can handle persistent connections based on events.

It should be possible (with NodeJS) to code a relay server (relaying from your phone to your home PC and vice versa) with only a few lines of code.

Comment: I'm halfway through [The Node Beginner Book](http://www.nodebeginner.org/), this sort of use-case seems to be what it's made for.  I'm becoming a fan.

Comment: This is not hole punching, that's just a proxy/relay. The point of hole punching is that the actual data goes directly between firewalled devices.